# Image not appear using splash screen react native

Tags: react-native

i want to put image in splash screen react native but it didnt work. im using this library https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

i put some text in it and it works fine. but the image doesnt appear at all. i tried it in android studio it works fine but when react native rendering image not appear at all

Image : png 32 bit

Here is it the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="Tes"
        android:textColor="#4972D1"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="Tes"
        android:textColor="#759fff"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is it in android studio
[image: Here is it in android studio]

Here is it when i launch the app
[image]

Comment: my bad, i put app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash" it should android:src="@drawable/splash"

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add in the image in Splash.xml and then re-build the project.

Also add the images in drawable folder.

Comment: why? please give some reason

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs, you should add scaleType property to your ImageView.

```
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

If it doesn't works please add your manifest file for further help.

Comment: you should be more specific about your error, Here, by official docs I mean to say about the official docs for the react-native-splash-screen. Its seems like you are making some problem on the android side, thus I asked you for the manifest file.